# How to control figure aspect ratio in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, aspect-ratio

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))

plot(t, loc.t)  # the x and y are random values. 
plot(t, scale.t)
plot(t, shape.t)
```

[image]

I work in a Jupyter Lab and have run the code above. However, I'm facing an issue where the figures are appearing too elongated in a row, rather than in a column.

I've attempted to control the figure ratios for rows and columns, but it seems that comments are not working as expected in my Jupyter Lab environment. I suspect that this issue may be related to the Jupyter Lab environment itself.

My goal is to display the figures (without saving them) within Jupyter Lab.

Example of my goal:

The figure I want can be drawn using `par(mfrow=c(3,3))`, but there are many gaps as below.
[image]

===============================================

Controlling the `asp=100` option changes the y-axis range of the figure, but the resulting aspect ratio of the figure is constant.
[image]

Comment: What would you want the figure  to look like? Would `par(mfrow=c(3, 1))` suffice? It would also be easier to help if you edited your question to include reproducible data. Good luck!

Comment: @Wayne Actually mentioning the target language is Not supposed to be in the title. That’s what tags are for. And I’m not sure what the “R kernel” might be. There is a suite of required packages, but the people in RCore do not refer to them as a “kernel”.

Comment: Jupyter R kernel is a kernel that lets you to run R code in Jupyter notebooks (ie, lets you execute R code in the notebook), not the language itself

Comment: The `graphics::plot` function has an 'asp' parameter that might allow control of the aspect ratio. Not sure how it handles that parameter with mfrow, though. You will get more effort from respondents if you include a [MCVE] but I will admit that building such a test case is not at all difficult here. But I'm too busy at the moment.